# Transitions Out of DOM

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I use d3 to generate an svg but don't always render to the DOM.  (sometimes canvas or webgl)
I want to use the transition interface to animate an SVG.

Ex: Make a circle fill attr go red -> blue in 10s.
During the transition I would use a timer to sample the svg and update the chosen renderer.

The problem is that transitions don't seem to start until the element is inserted in the DOM even if I only want to interpolate a color attribute.

I could get this working with a headless DOM like the one suggested for node, but would like not to incur so much extra infrastructure if possible.

Is there any way to start the transition for attributes of out-of-dom elements?

Comment: I think there is no way to do it 'out of DOM'. If you want to calculate color transition - it's very simple: incrementing blue and decrementing red value of RGB every  ~39 milliseconds  will make transition from red `(rgb 255,0,0)` to blue `(rgb 0,0,255)` in 10 seconds

Comment: Right. I could also use d3 interpolation, timers & generators for each sort of transition I wanted, but I was hoping  to leverage the great tools d3 already has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D3 transitions are built on top of DOM nodes – they store state there, so if you want to do animation on non-DOM nodes, you'll need a different animation engine. From the d3-transition docs:

> A transition is a selection-like interface for animating changes to the **DOM**.

Some generic animation JS libraries I've found helpful in the past for this purpose include:

- [anime.js](https://animejs.com/)
- [Popmotion](https://popmotion.io/)
- [Tween.js](https://www.createjs.com/tweenjs)
- [GreenSock GSAP](https://greensock.com/gsap/)

Here's an example for animating color with anime.js: ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/animejs-color-example-cebev?file=/src/index.js:0-480))

```js
import "./styles.css";
import anime from "animejs";

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<svg width="500" height="300">
  <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="25" fill="red" />
</svg>
`;

const state = {
  color: "rgb(255,0,0)"
};

const circle = document.querySelector("circle");

anime({
  targets: state,
  color: "rgb(0,0,255)",
  easing: "linear",
  loop: true,
  duration: 1000,
  direction: "alternate",
  update: function () {
    circle.style.fill = state.color;
  }
});
```

Note that this animates the *state object*, not the *DOM*, which leaves flexibility for you in terms of how you render it.